# I can't see my cursor after Partial Upgrade

Tags: xorg, mouse, cursor

So, I had installed a newer version of Gedit and Rhythmbox on Ubuntu 13.10. Then, I rebooted, and it asked me to do a partial upgrade. So, I said yes and let it do its thing.

I watched what it was doing, and it said it ran out of memory, but continued normally. (It was out of memory on the partition with Ubuntu on it). I restarted the computer again so the changes would take affect, and my login screen was almost all white.

I put in my password and it logged me in and everything looked normal. Then I noticed, the cursor was gone! I have a mouse, and can click on things, but I can't see where I'm moving the mouse because the cursor is gone!

How to fix this ?

Comment: Could you add the output of `cat ~/.xsession-errors` and `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already got a solution, but the same problem happened for me and I was told to use:
`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false`

It will restore it, but you need to do it in each account.

Hopefully you already solved this!